# Incorrect exception adress for MIPS Malta in QEMU?

Tags: exception, mips, qemu

I'm writing a small kernel for MIPS Malta on a Linux machine, Ubuntu 18.04, and emulating the host using QEMU. When trying to implement exception handling however, I'm confused by the memory mapping provided by Qemu. Most of the documentation online seems to claim that adress `0x80000080` is the adress that the CPU jumps to in the case of an exception, but when debugging i GDB Qemu seems to want to go to `0xbfc00384` instead.

I understand that this is likely due to Qemu merely simulating the Malta board but I haven't been able to find any documentation on how Qemu maps the memory. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/986507/Mips-Technologies-Malta.html?page=13) for the memory map. Flash memory is shown at `0x1FC0.0000` (equivalent to `0xBFC0.0000`).  `0x80000000` is typically RAM.